# Optimizing Query Performance on a Partitioned Table Based on Multiple Date Columns

Tags: postgresql

I am seeking some advice on a particular case I'm dealing with.

I have a transaction table with three date columns, namely transaction date, settlement date, and approval date. At present, the volume of data in this table has grown significantly and in order to improve performance, I'm planning to partition the transaction table.

If I partition the table based on the transaction date, queries using the WHERE clause on the transaction date become faster. However, when I run queries using a WHERE clause on the settlement date or approval date, the performance significantly decreases as the database needs to search the entire primary table.

What is the best advice to overcome this issue? How can I partition data based on all three date columns without sacrificing query performance on the other columns? Is there a specific partitioning strategy that I can use, or are there other approaches that might be more efficient?

Thank you in advance for any advice and assistance.

Comment: Partitioning won't improve performance for you. Create the appropriate index(es) instead.

Comment: Step one would be the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) and the DDL for tables and indexes involved. If you share that information, please use plain text as an update to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no practical way to partition for three independent dimensions.  Even two is tricky.  See [*Partition*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

It sounds like your queries include

```
WHERE `customer_id` = 1234   -- single customer
  AND `some-date` >= ...     -- one of your 3 dates
ORDER BY `some-date`         -- (if needed)
```

**Plan A:**

When you have an `=` and some other test, have an `INDEX(es)` starting with the `=` column:

```
INDEX(customer_id, trans_date)
INDEX(customer_id, settle_date)
INDEX(customer_id, approve_date)
```

Each of these will help performance at least as good as partitioning -- and this helps all three.

To discuss further, please provide some samples of the main queries.

**Plan B:**

Assuming you have lots of customers, but each customer does not have many rows in the table, then this approach may be even faster:

```
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, id),   -- to cluster by customer_id
INDEX(id)      -- sufficient to keep AUTO_INC happy
```

This clusters the customer records near each other.  Hence, searching by any date and even [if needed] sorting becomes "fast enough".  The indexes of Plan A are not likely to be helpful and possibly never used by the Optimizer.

This Plan even helps with searching for customer records based on other criteria.

**Summarization?**

Do you also need to tally all the info, system-wide, for a given week or month?  If so, we can discuss how to build and maintain [*Summary Tables*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)